# Shelosha Ushloshim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred thirty three?

### שלשה ושלושים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 333? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 333, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answers consisting of lazy *gematria* will be as welcome as snow in April.

Comment: ITYM "Answers consisting of lazy gematria will be as welcome as snow in April, mate."

Comment: @msh210, There are probably places where snow is welcome in April, but which hemisphere they're on is not the determining factor.

Comment: No, I was adding in another lazy _gimatriya_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

333 is the Gematria of שלג (snow) as well as שכחה (forgetfulness). Rabbi Tzadok of Lublin notes the connection in that the coldness of Amalek which cools excitement for Torah and Mitzvos.

[Source](http://www.aish.com/sp/k/48968661.html).

Answer (score 5):

[Bava Metzia 104b](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%90_%D7%A7%D7%93_%D7%91) mentions [a story of](http://www.come-and-hear.com/babamezia/babamezia_104.html)

> a certain man once leased a field from his neighbour and stated: 'If I
>   do not cultivate it, I will give you a thousand zuz.'9  Now, he left a
>   third uncultivated. Said the Nehardeans: It is but just that he should
>   pay him three hundred thirty-three one-third zuz.
>
> ההוא גברא דקבל ארעא מחבריה אמר אי מוברנא לה יהיבנא לך אלפא זוזי אוביר
>   תילתא אמרי נהרדעי דינא הוא דיהיב ליה תלת מאה ותלתין ותלתא ותילתא

Answer (score 3):

[Megilas Damesek - page 36](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rto-AAAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA36&lpg=RA1-PA36&dq=%D7%A9%D7%9C%22%D7%92+%D7%9E%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%22%D7%90&source=bl&ots=fgrZe9JlcJ&sig=jcdUP7_IZ_5JSeW7xHm2DO4yDP4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aMQ3VfyjNJPkgwT-iIOACA&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%D7%A9%D7%9C%22%D7%92%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%22%D7%90&f=false) supplies an interesting answer. Although it is matter of dispute, there are those that contend that the Rama who passed away on Lag B'Omer, died in the year 5333 (של"ג).